# Why my buffer is overkill? (C++ exception: std::bad_alloc)

Tags: c++, memory

When I run my code it returns an error (Unhandled exception in 0x768C43D2 in MemoryReadTest.exe: Microsoft C ++ exception: std :: bad_alloc in memory location 0x0019F640. Occurred)

I think the problem is my buffer, does anyone know how I can solve this error?

(The purpose of my code is to scan strings in the memory of a program)

```cpp
void main()
{
    DWORD systemPid = 123;
    HANDLE systemH = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, systemPid);
    if (systemH && systemPid > 4)
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
        char* p = 0;
        //std::vector<char> chunk; // Old Buffer
        while (p < si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress)
        {
            if (VirtualQueryEx(systemH, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info))
            {
                //chunk.resize(info.RegionSize); // Old Buffer
                char* chunk = new char[info.RegionSize];
                p = (char*)info.BaseAddress;
                SIZE_T bytesRead;

                if (ReadProcessMemory(systemH, p, &chunk[0], info.RegionSize, &bytesRead))
                {
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < (bytesRead - 3); ++i)
                    {

                        if (memcmp("exe", &chunk[i], 3) == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "Found";
                        }


                    }
                }
                delete[] chunk;
                p += info.RegionSize;
            }
        }
        cout << "Finish";
    }
}
```

Comment: You allocate a bunch of memory blocks, but you don't deallocate any of them. They are all leaked. Eventually, you run out of memory.

Comment: How can I deallocate?

Comment: I see you added `delete[] chunk;` It wasn't there originally. Did it help?

Comment: You should look at `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::State`, and only attempt to read `MEM_COMMIT` regions.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `if ReadProcessMemory` block? It looks like the first `VirtualQueryEx` call that fails will cause the big `while` to loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    if (memcmp("exe", &chunk[i], 14) == 0)
```

This compares up to 14 bytes of the two blocks of memory. But the string "exe" is only four bytes ('e', 'x', 'e' and a terminating nul). So you are reading up to 10 bytes past the end of the chunk of memory in which this string is stored.

You should also sanity check `bytesRead`. What if it's 1? You should sanity check `info.RegionSize` as well. You should `delete[] chunk;` when you're done with it rather than accumulating more and more lost chunks.

Comment: Oh yes, I made that mistake too, thank you very much for correcting it, but the error I mentioned continues

Comment: Well, I did what you said and it seems to have progressed well, the program managed to scan more memory and send more results, but it still gives the error I mentioned, even after doing what you said

Comment: Did you fix all four issues? Can you add the updated code to your question? (Don't remove the existing code. Add the updated code at the end.)

Comment: I think I made all the changes as you said, but about doing an `info.RegionSize` check, I didn't quite understand how it would work

Comment: @DeathZ_ I think he is saying to check the size of that value. If it is too big, that might be the cause of your exception

Comment: If RegionSize is a trillion, will your code do something sane? If RegionSize is 1, will your code do something sane? If the answer to either of these questions is "no", then you need to add sanity checks.